# pandas.read_csv turns strings into 'numbers' in scientific notation (which I don't want)

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-notation

I have a dataset where some of the sample identifiers (found in the index column) can be interpreted as numbers.  Examples: 20010104123140E5 and 2001010412314529. I try to specify that the index column has type string, but pandas.read_csv insists on turning identifiers into floats. See example below.

Does anyone know how I can get around this? Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd

with open('test.data', mode = 'w') as infile: 
    infile.write('id\tval\n20010104123140E5\t1\n2001010412314529\t2')

df = pd.read_csv('test.data', dtype = {'id':'str', 'val':'float'}, sep='\t', index_col='id')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 
df.index = df.index.astype(str)